# How to name multiple ranges with VBA?

Tags: vba, named-ranges

I am stuck on this beginner issue. I would like to name 400 ranges as per the image attached. The name would be Range_1, Range_2 etc. The error is the reference to current region.

[image: Ranges]

```
Sub NameRange_Add()

    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim Reference As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 2
        RangeName = "Range_" & i
        Reference = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
        Worksheets("Test").Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Reference
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you determining the start and end of each named range? Is it all in one sheet?

Comment: It's odd that two people want to do [such a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50927103/8112776) so close together...  my comment is the same: Is there a reason you need to use named ranges instead of referring to the cells dynamically? Named Ranges aren't really intended to be used in this way.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes, its all on one sheet - yes it is weird. Sorry halfer I did not intentionally add urgent, did not even know it was marked urgent. Thanks for the heads-up